# PHP Email $Subject Line Will Not Pull Variable

Tags: php

I've searched around with no luck here. I created a PHP email form that works great. Now I need to edit the email subject line to pull information from the contact form.

Here's what I'm looking to have as the email subject line:
"You have a $variable inquiry from $variable.

Here's my current code that is giving me an error on the $Subject line:

```
$EmailFrom = "Contact@xxx.com";
$EmailTo = "ryan@xxx.com";
$Subject = "You have a .$Subj inquiry from .$Name";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['sender_name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['sender_email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));
$System = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['system']));
$Item = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['item'])); 
$Subj = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['subj']));
```

So I have tried adding a <> around the variables in the $Subject. I have also tried with the periods as above, as well as with just the $xxx.

When I send the email, it will send as:
"You have a <> inquiry from <>"
or
"You have a . inquiry from ."
Depending on which characters I have around the $xxx variable.

I know this is probably some stupid error, but can someone hint me at what I need to do to have those variable pulled into the $Subject?

Thanks in advance,
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your variable declarations out of order.

You are using `$Name` in the first line before you have assigned a value to it.  You need to put the lines that give values to `$Name` and `$Subj` before the line that uses them.

Comment: Okay. If I just mnove it around, it will not have any output effect, though?

Comment: The code that you posted doesn't do any output at all.